ELIFECYCLE Command failed with exit code 1. Error: Process completed with exit code 1
ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1. Error: Process completed with exit code 1. in GitHub cli workflow using ts
What I tried
CI=false npm run build
npm install --save-dev lint-staged
commitlint.yml
name: CI

  CI=false npm run build

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  commitlint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Install required dependencies
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt install -y sudo
          sudo apt install -y git curl
          curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
          sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y nodejs
      - name: Print versions
        run: |
          git --version
          node --version
          npm --version
          npx commitlint --version
      - name: Install commitlint
        run: |
          npm install conventional-changelog-conventionalcommits
          npm install commitlint@latest
          npm install --save-dev lint-staged
      - name: Validate current commit (last commit) with commitlint
        if: github.event_name == 'push'
        run: npx commitlint --last --verbose

      - name: Validate PR commits with commitlint
        if: github.eventxname == 'pull_request'
        run: npx commitlint --from ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}~${{ github.event.pull_request.commits }} --to ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }} --verbose


my .eslintrc.cjs
module.exports = {
    env: { browser: true, es2020: true },
    extends: [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
    ],
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    parserOptions: { ecmaVersion: "latest", sourceType: "module" },
    plugins: ["react-refresh"],
    rules: {
        "react-refresh/only-export-components": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types": "off",
        "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": 0, 
        'prefer-const': 'warn',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function': 'off',

    },
};

